zmk: can't make behaviors work as expected
I have 3 layers:
#define DEFAULT 0
#define LOWER   1
#define RAISE   2

On DEFAULT layer, I need a key with this behaviour:

hold: momentary enables LOWER layer
tap: enable LOWER layer
tap then hold: momentary enables RAISE layer

On LOWER layer, I need a key with this behaviour:

hold: momentary enables RAISE layer
tap: enable RAISE layer

